# Bug on background image after wrong password

Tags: html, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I have a bug on the login page of my project, the background image simple disappear when a wrong passowrd is inputed.

I think it might be because of the URL of the page (if a wrong password is inputed, a "?error=true" is added to the url: "localhost:xxxx/login?error=true")

But I have no idea of how to fix this...

Im using spring, thymeleaf and html5, css3, js and boostrap

Thanks

My css:

```
.newbackground{
    background: url('../img/bg_image1.jpg');

}
```

Js:

```
<script>

    var x = document.URL;

    var conditions = ["?error=true"];

    var test1 = conditions.some(el => x.includes(el));

    if(test1 == true){
    alert("Wrong Password!");
    }

    </script>
```

My html is like this:

```
<body class="newbackground">
<!-- [+] container -->
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Autenticação</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" role="form">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Login" name="login"
                                        type="text" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"
                                        type="password" value="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-group btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"
                                        type="submit" value="Enter" />
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you might want to post some html, css and javascript if that is used that is relevant to the login control you are talking about. Btw welcome to SO, but you should read the manual on how to post a question or there is a big chance this will be downvoted or even closed due to poor quality.

Comment: Ok, I'll post some parts of the code